# Visual Studio 2019 VB suddenly slow running code in debug mode

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I’m using VB 2019 with the latest updates on 64-bit Windows 10 with the same. In the past few days I’ve started having a 30-40 second delay when loading my code in debug mode. Up until a couple of days ago this only took about 5 seconds. Any ideas what might have happened and/or how I can reduce this delay starting up my code every time I make a change to it?

Windows updated a couple of items each of the last couple of nights, I wonder if any of these have triggered the new behavior.

Comment: (in win 10) Open TaskMan. Which task is a) using the most Memory, b) using the most CPU? (just in case there is an outside cause)

Comment: There are few practical explanations for such long delays.  You're down to anti-malware getting is underwear in a bundle about an .exe file appearing from seemingly no-where, temporarily disable it to see if that makes a difference.  And a socket connection timeout (like a CRL server), use SysInternals' TcpView to diagnose.

Comment: Checking Task Manager identified the problem -- the anti-virus software. We disabled the anti-virus and the problem went away. Apparently it was examining every new copy of the .exe file that was created (with every build), comparing it to a database of known problems, scanning it, etc. So that's what was taking all the time.

Answer (score 0):

The reason may be that many files are created during compilation, and the anti-virus tool provided by Microsoft will scan the created files, so the compilation speed is reduced.

You can set a folder whitelist in the Windows Security Center, which is Windows Defender. Files in this folder will not be scanned. Putting my own code warehouse, I will put all my code in a folder, add this folder to the whitelist, it will not be scanned during compilation, which can speed up the compilation speed.

Comment: There's a different anti-virus system in use -- not Windows Defender.